# In Windows Vista, what IRQL is the thread scheduler run at?

Tags: windows-vista, multithreading, scheduling

In Vista, what IRQL is the thread scheduler run at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's run at `DISPATCH_LEVEL`, which is IRQL 2 on x86. (I think this value may be different for different architectures, however.)